# turn off screen from UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-application

I am creating an UWP application which will run in Kiosk Mode, based on some message from TCP/IP communication I Want to turn off and turn on screen from UWP application.

I tried using SendMessage but it didn't worked. Am I missing anything? Or there is any other way?

```
public class MyClass
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
    public void DisplaySettingChange(bool flag)
    {
       if(flag)
           SendMessage(IntPtr.Zero, 0x112, 0xF170, 1);
       else
           SendMessage(IntPtr.Zero, 0x112, 0xF170, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: afaik you won't be able to turn off the display directly from a UWP, because it runs in a sandbox. If you want to access anything "outside", you'll need to do it via an additional application. Have a look at FullTrustProcess to do so.

Comment: Does the answer make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @Mahobo mentioned, it is not possible to do that in UWP apps. There is no such native UWP API that could do it. UWP apps are running in the Sandbox so they are limited to access some system resource and functions.

You might try to do it in a normal application, like a console exe. Then you could launch it from the UWP app to do what you want.